# How can you passively respond to a RoutedCommand?

Tags: wpf, routed-events

Our application is based on a stack of pages, which are just subclasses of a `FrameworkElement`.  The main window maintains that stack and uses the built-in `Close` command to close them by simply popping them off the stack.

Now in some cases, the element being closed (or popped-off the stack) needs to do some cleanup first.  Having that page also listen to the `Close` event seemed like the right thing to do.

Now, since that page would actually get the event before the window (the `Close` command is implemented via a 'bubbling event') we thought all we had to do was to set the command binding on the page, then in the handler, set `e.Handled` to false and it would continue up to the window.

Here's the code in the page (`InitializeCommands` is called from the constructor)...

```
private void InitializeCommands(){

    CommandBindings.Add(
        new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Close, Close_Execute, Close_CanExecute)
    );
}

private void Close_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e){
    // True executes this handler, but blocks the one in the window
    // False executes the one in the window, but ignores this one
    e.CanExecute = true;

    // Doesn't seem to have any effect
    e.Handled = false;
}
private void Close_Execute(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e){
    Console.WriteLine("I want to respond passively!");
    // Doesn't seem to have any effect
    e.Handled = false;
}
```

However, regardless of what we set that property to, the command never makes it to the main window.  If we remove the command binding in the page, it works again, proving the page is swallowing the command regardless of that property.

So what do you have to do to make the page listen to the `Close` event passively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, CommandBinding eats commands.  Here's an excerpt of its implementation:

```
internal void OnExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Handled)
    {
        if (e.RoutedEvent == CommandManager.ExecutedEvent)
        {
            if (this.Executed != null && CheckCanExecute(sender, e))
            {
                this.Executed(sender, e);
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
        else if (this.PreviewExecuted != null && CheckCanExecute(sender, e))
        {
            this.PreviewExecuted(sender, e);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, if you return true for CanExecute, the commands get eaten.

You might want to take a look at CompositeCommand. That'd be more up your alley. You create a global CompositeCommand that is bound to the frame and then different views can attach to it. Different implementations can have different cool ways of determining how multiple subscribers to the commands behave. I.e. all must return canExecute, any must return, only goes to the active view, etc.

EDIT: CompositeCommand was originally part of Prism, but you can either find a standalone implementation or just yank the one from Prism itself:

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism/Commands/CompositeCommand.cs

Comment: Thanks.  I'll definitely check this out.  I also read up on MVVM Light which has some `Message` thing that also looks promising.  An FYI unrelated to my question, in your example, unless you're subscribing to the event manually and explicitly saying you want to handle already-handled events, your outer `if(!e.Handled)` check isn't needed as the event won't ever be raised if it has already been handled elsewhere.

Comment: @MarqueIV The code snippet is from the WPF source code, not mine :). I was just showing you why CommandBindings eat your messages. They hardcoded the e.Handled = true. You mean Messenger? That's an event aggregator. Some VM posts messages to the "event bus" and it gets distributed to anybody that subscribed to the message. It definitely has its place in MVVM, but since you are already working with commands, I'd go with the CompositeCommand. Essentially the same thing at a mile high conceptual level, but things play nicer with commands vs custom msgs :)

Comment: @MarqueIV I use Messenger when VMs need to notify each other. If you just used a command to utilize bubbling then that's different. CompositeCommand would be useful for something like Save / SaveAll. For the Save command you set up the command to only go to the active view, but for SaveAll you'd set it up to go to all views, etc.

Comment: @MarqueIV See here https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/wpf/Advanced-MVVM.html for a diagram... its the 2nd section down. If you are just trying to get VMs to communicate and don't need UI interaction, then I'd go with Messenger.

Comment: Essentially what I'm trying to do is have the 'Close' command--which is handled by the main window to actually close the editor--also do some processing on the editor itself, specific to that editor.  Originally I had code in the editor's destructor, but that of course doesn't fire until the GC runs.  Based on that statement, which do you recommend, Messenger or the CompositeCommand?

Comment: Oh, and thanks for the very extensive and helpful comments here! May be a good idea to put the highlights right in the answer itself so others can more easily find it. But again, really great stuff!

Comment: @MarqueIV For that I think you're over complicating it with either solution. Why not have an IEditor type interface with bool CanClose / void Close? Or you can put it in a base class. I just did a project where I had a common base class for my various document VMs and it implemented the rough plumbing type stuff like that. If you start doing that with commands or messages, it'll become a mess (close / canclose / dirty detection, etc).

Comment: @MarqueIV I'd use composite command where it ties into button type UI elements (like the save / save as example) and messenger for behind the scenes VM to VM communication. One example of that might be Visual Studio. Double clicking on a file in the file view might post a message to the main frame to spin up the appropriate VM for the file.

Comment: That doesn't really solve anything.  Again, to the window, 'Close' just means 'Pop whatever's on the stack off of it'.  It doesn't need to check anything about the content it's popping (i.e. that it supports IEditor or whatever.) In contrast, the editor just needs to know it's being closed, but nothing is telling it it's being popped off the stack.  If however they both responded to the 'Close' command, then neither needs to know about the other and everything would just work. Make sense?

Comment: @MarqueIV Yes. I meant that the thing that's popping stuff off the stack would know about the IEditor or whatever you want to call it interface and call the CanClose to allow the VM to abort the close and then if true, pop it off the stack and call the close method to allow for clean up.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just not crazy about having to add an interface that the window knows about.  Seems like three-lefts-to-go-right.  Plus, it means I need to inspect what I'm popping rather than just blindly doing it.  Still, it would give more options (i.e. ability to cancel, etc.) so I guess it's not all that bad. I just wished I could peek that the message is being closed.

Comment: Either way, marking this as the answer because it does give me a solution.

Comment: @MarqueIV it'd be the exact same concept with messenger pattern... "some one" (the thing popping it off the stack) would have to post the closing message. Either of the three ways, at some point, somebody has to "send" "something". At that point, imho, it's cleaner to just do a "is IEditor", if so use the interface.

Comment: But a button *does* post the 'ApplicationCommands.close' command, which already tells me everything I need to know.  I just needed both the window and the editor to handle that command, which doesn't look like it's possible.

Comment: @MarqueIV messenger or commands would make it a lot harder to implement the cancel. CompositeCommand would let you "peek" at the message.

Comment: @MarqueIV Actually... one more option for you that might be what you want... take a look at AddHandler(). I think that's what you're looking for. That'll let you catch the events from children without eating them.

Comment: @MarqueIV For example, in my BreadCumb control, I want to catch all the BreadCrumbButton  click events, so I can do AddHandler(BreadcrumbSplitButton.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnBreadcrumbSplitButtonClick));

Comment: Mind posting an answer with the AddHandler example?  I may switch it to that one.

Answer (score 0):

One additional idea is take a look at the AddHandler() method. That let's you add a single event handler for all the child events. I.e. for my bread crumb control, I can do:

AddHandler(BreadcrumbSplitButton.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnBreadcrumbSplitButtonClick));

In the BreadCrumb class to listen for the ClickEvent from all children BreadcrumbSplitButtons.

Comment: Oh... I misunderstood.  This is one handler for many sources.  I need the opposite.  Many handlers (i.e. on the window and the editor) for one source (the close command from the main menu)

Comment: @MarqueIV Sounds like your best bet is CompositeCommand then. I'd use that since you're tying it in to a button / menu type control. That'll let multiple views listen to the one button.